# How to open non-valid HTML (from Wikipedia) via document() in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, html-parsing, html-entities, wikipedia

I use XSLT 1.0 to extract information from Wikipedia infoboxes, and, for certain links, fetch additional information from further Wikipedia sites.

In principle, this works fine, unless the HTML returned for the Wikipedia pages is invalid. Unfortunately, this happens for all pages in, e.g., the Russian Wikipedia. Try the following example

```
<xsl:for-each 
     select="document('http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0')//text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The trouble is that the entity ® is used on every page in this language edition, but not declared: The HTML declaration of Wikipedia pages is crippled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Instead of, say,

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This is clearly a Wikipedia issue, not an XSLT issue, but is there any workaround to parse these sites nevertheless? Any pointers to a more robust XSLT parser? Is there any way to infuse entity declarations into the HTML before it gets parsed?

So far, I tried XSLTproc, Saxon6.5.5, Saxon-B 9.1.0.8, and Xalan, all with the same result.

Comment: Isn't XSLT just for XML? HTML is not XML.

Comment: clearly a wikipedia issue is correct. you should post to wikipedia and not xslt.

Comment: The doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the standard conforming HTML declaration which would put a modern browser in "standards mode" The `xhtml1-transitional.dtd"` in an HTML file would be a syntax error as that is an XML DTD and the syntax of XML is different,

Comment: Right, I actually talked to the Wikipedia people directly. Wikipedia uses HTML5, and the declaration is correct. The trouble is my XSLT tools have trouble with the (actually valid) HTML5. And, yes, XSLT is for HTML, too. Originally, it was supposed to replace CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Saxon and Xalan (I don't know about xsltproc) allow you to supply a URIResolver to handle document() requests. This is allowed to return any Source object. To process HTML input, return a SAXSource whose XMLReader is actually an HTML parser. There are a couple of candidates, [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) and [validator.nu](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/) - the latter is probably better as it claims to implement the HTML5 parsing algorithm. The XSLT processor will then think it is dealing with well-formed XML.

Alternatively, in Saxon there is a [saxon:parse-html()](http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/parse-html) extension function. This in fact uses TagSoup underneath.

Comment: Yes, that's been it. Eventually, I used http://web-xslt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl as an out-of-the-box solution with Saxon 9 HE. (saxon:parse-html requires PE or EE). The only drawback is that it really requires XSLT 2.0. Thanks a lot!